# Facebook iframe is showing up in the middle of my Joomla article

Tags: facebook, joomla

Facebook iframe is showing up in the middle of my Joomla article.  I am wanting to make it go away and have tried nearly everything I could think of. Please help! the article link is http://blowingrocknews.com/community-life/general-news/2658-tis-the-season-forgetting-your-teeth-knocked-out.html

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove the old FBML style of Facebook commenting, and instead switch to using Social Plugins, like https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/